# Excel: Items in column moved to specific location based on value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do the following

In sheet 1. I have a list of items in Column A. Each Item as a specific category in Column B. 
I'd like to dynamically update Sheet 2 which behaves like a summary sheet(of the list on Sheet 1). On sheet 2 the items from Column A (Sheet 1) are organized based on the category

any input would be great

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Not sure what you mean by "dynamically update". Have you considered a pivot table?

Comment: Welcome! This site is for questions more related to programming, and not questions about using software. For more info, see the [FAQ].

Comment: @user2510844 .. what's the summary look like ?